# Override asp net web form action

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have the following web form:

Working Form:

```
<form id="transactionParameters" method="post" runat="server" action="remote_url.aspx">
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                <label for="Username">Username:</label>
                <asp:TextBox id="Username" Text="TomSelleck" runat="server" />
            </p>

            <asp:Button ID="SubmitForm" runat="server" onclick="SubmitForm_Click" Text="Button" />  
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

And this successfully submits the form value `Username` to `remote_url.aspx` and brings the user to the remote page.

The problem I face is that I need to add a value to the form before submitting the form and redirecting the user e.g:

Desired functionality:

```
<form id="transactionParameters" method="post" runat="server">
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                <label for="Username">Username:</label>
                <asp:TextBox id="Username" Text="TomSelleck" runat="server" />
            </p>

            <asp:Button ID="SubmitForm" runat="server" onclick="SubmitForm_Click" Text="Button" />  
        </fieldset>
</form>


// This method is fired but I don't know how to execute the commented out code
protected void SubmitForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Form["Username"] = Username.Text.Uppercase();
    // Form["NewValue"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();

    // ExecuteAction(Form, "remote_url.aspx");
}
```

Comment: `OnClientClick` does not work or have a class style and have a jQuery listener on the button does not work?

Comment: `SubitForm_Click` is fired - but I don't know how to execute the pseudocode I've commented out

Comment: Are you trying to pass the value from the one page to the other?

Comment: Yep exactly - so when I submit the form in my first example - the form elements are passed to the `action="remote_url.aspx"` and the user is directed to that page. I would like to do the same thing inside my `SubmitForm_Click` method

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in several different ways.

- Query String
- Session
- Cookie
- Internal variable / object

The question will be what are the requirements?  The easiest would be the Query String, simply do `Response.Redirect("...aspx?username=Tom");`.

Then on the other form you would simply parse the Query String.  `Request.QueryString["username"]?.ToString()`.

The drawback would be your url has a username in clear text and is exposed easily.  The Session would store a unique identifier of that information into a cookie, making those approaches similar.  But equally easy and may meet your requirements.

An internal object variable after the method fires, storing that object in memory making it accessible and exposed on the other page load event will work also.

Comment: I need to send the variables as form data, not as query parameters. I would like to replicate the exact same functionality as `<form id="transactionParameters" method="post" runat="server" action="remote_url.aspx">`

Comment: Why?  If you have a user filling out a form why would their result or form data need to be redirected and not handled in the initial postback?

Comment: I need to add a parameter to the form before submitting it. The parameter is calculated based on what the user has entered

Comment: Can you provide an example?  Why on the postback can you not add the parameter based on what they entered?

Comment: The postback being the `SubmitForm_Click`? That's my question - how do I replicate exactly what `<form id="transactionParameters" method="post" runat="server" action="remote_url.aspx">` does - except inside my `SubmitForm_Click`?

Comment: Honestly I am not entirely sure what the issue is, the context I have derived is that you appear to be fighting the post back, you want to perform a post back but during that submission or before the post back executes you want code to be executed to return back to that form.

Comment: Sorry - I'm probably not making myself clear because I'm unfamiliar with the framework. 

Basically - I need to do a calculation based on what the user has entered into the form, add the result as a variable to the form (as a hidden element for example) and then POST it to the remote server. The problem is, I can't see any way to do a postback to calculate my value and then submit the form.

Comment: @TomSelleck I assume you want to validate the content before the post back?  So it does not impede user workflow?

Comment: From the users point of view, they just fill out a form and click submit - from my point of view, when they click submit - I want to calculate a variable and add it to the form, then forward the request onto the remote url

Comment: What is the purpose of forwarding to the remote url?

Comment: To submit the document

Comment: Why do you need for forward onward if the current page is actually submitting the form?

Comment: I have to do a calculation based on what the user has entered. Once the calculation is completed, the result is submitted with the rest of the users answers as a form to the remote url. This calculation needs to be done by my server, not the remote.

Comment: So why would you not wrap the page in an update panel?  Then let them execute the calculation, then after submit the form?  Why are you separating?  Some information is not being provided.  But if I was reviewing a junior dev, the workflow you provided would be flagged.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to implement this as an update panel? As I said before - I'm unfamiliar with asp net webforms. I am at a loss as why this simple task is so difficult achieve in webforms. `1. User enters data 2. User clicks submit 3. Form is sent to my server 4. A calculation (e.g a hash digest of what the user has entered) is done by my server 5. The user, along with the form (containing the hash digest I calculated), is submitted as a post request to a remote server.`

Comment: No I'm afraid not - I don't see how that is relevant.

Comment: The relevance would be, why does your web site that is taking a form need to send form data to a remote server?  Unless the requirements are for a database, authentication server api, or another api your web application should handle itself likely.  But if you must do that, on the button event you would turn the form data into a json object an instantiate a web request to that server.  Which would then parse your object and handle, obviously I'm unaware of your architecture though.  So I cannot say that is ideal.